# Deactivate Draw Controls when Panel is Closed

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a control panel that when the center button is clicked another panel containing the draw control features is toggled and displayed(image example below)[image: Map Tools button is clicked, draw control feature panel displayed]

What I would like to happen is that when I click the "Map Tools" button again and the draw controls panel is hidden, all controls within this panel are automatically deactivated.

For the panel toggle I am using a simple jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".olControlCustomNavToolbar").hide();

    $("a#map_tools").click(function(event){
            $(".tools").find(".olControlCustomNavToolbar").toggle();
            if($(".print_pref").is(":visible")){
                    $(".print_pref").hide();
            }
            return false;
    });
});
```

For the draw controls I kinda mixed it up a bit to customize(so please don't go off on me say the CustomNavToolbar is not supposed to be used this way)

```
OpenLayers.Control.CustomNavToolbar=OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control.Panel,{
    initialize:function(options){
            OpenLayers.Control.Panel.prototype.initialize.apply(this,[options]);
            this.addControls([
                    new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vlayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon,{displayClass:'olControlDrawPolygon'}),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vlayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Path,{displayClass:'olControlDrawPath'}),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vlayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Point,{displayClass:'olControlDrawPoint'})
            ])
            this.displayClass='olControlCustomNavToolbar'
    }
});
```

Hope someone can help. Would be very appreciated if there is any other code that would be helpful I'll post it ASAP. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [deactivate](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.deactivate) the control by calling `myControl.deactivate()`.

## Update

[Here's an example](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/draw-feature.html) per your request in comment.

Notice now when the navigate option is clicked all drawControls are deactivated.

relevant code:

```js
function toggleControl(element) {
    for(key in drawControls) {
        var control = drawControls[key];
        if(element.value == key && element.checked) {
            control.activate();
        } else {
            control.deactivate();
        }
    }
}
```

## Update #2 Per Comment:

If you want to deactivate all the controls when your toolbar is

```js
$("a#map_tools.myButton").click(function (event) {
    if ($(".olControlCustomNavToolbar").is(":visible") == false) {
        var controls = OpenLayers.Control.CustomNavToolbar.controls
        for (x in controls) {
            var control = controls[x].deactivate();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi #capdragon, thank you for the reply do I call this function within the jQuery when I toggle the panel or do I create a separate function for this?

Comment: Well, i would call `myControl.activate()` whenever you're user clicks on the draw icon. and `myControl.deactivate()` whenever he is done. I suppose if you are using jQuery to toggle the visual toolbar, then yes  do it within the jquery toggle callback function.

Comment: Hi capdragon...if possible could you give me an example? Having a bit of hard time wrapping my head around it

Comment: Hi capdragon. Thank you for your reply, yes I am using this to toggle the controls within the panel, but this method deactivates the controls when another control is selected.. What I am trying to do is deactivate all controls when the panel is hidden(in this case with the globe icon) by a button that is not a control or part of the panel